# problem with display datagrid with the values from dropdownlist asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, select

Hello its my first question, sorry for english i will try to clear write my problem.
I have 2 databased. First - "klienci" where are id_klienta imie and second where is id_klienta and id_filmu.
Im trying to choose by dropdownlist 'imie' and set id_klienta, and later show on datagrid 'id_klienta' and 'id_filmu' (and few columns more-i think its not important right now). I made 2 connections and I have a dropdown list with 'imie' but when I select one from the list the datagrid doesn't show anything(actually i cant see even only empty datagrid). Visible is true, where should I look for the reason?

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [id_klienta], [imie], [nazwisko] FROM [klienci]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [id_klienta], [id_filmu], [start], [stop] FROM [wypozyczenia] WHERE ([id_klienta] = @id_klienta)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="id_klienta" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="imie" DataValueField="id_klienta">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_klienta" HeaderText="id_klienta" SortExpression="id_klienta" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id_filmu" HeaderText="id_filmu" SortExpression="id_filmu" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="start" HeaderText="start" SortExpression="start" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="stop" HeaderText="stop" SortExpression="stop" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

My second question is if is it possible to show in this dropdownlist both values from the database? I mean now I have only 'imie' and I would like have 'imie' and 'nazwisko' ?
Thanks a lot for help!!!!

Comment: You need to add `AutoPostBack=true` to `DropDownList1`

Comment: I have added an answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `AutoPostBack="True"` to `DropDownList1` so that when you select an item from dropdown list server be able to run query and change the data source of gridview:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="imie" DataValueField="id_klienta">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

See how `AutoPostBack` property works:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback

Comment: Thank you :)
Do you know how can I display on my drpdownlist1 both columns 'imie'&'nazwisko'? I tried to made another one columns (select both) but it doesnt work for me. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. Please post that as a new question with enough information so that people can help.